# Can somone please explain how an empty set can be a subset of a Cartesian Product?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Observe that $\emptyset \subseteq A×A$, so $R = \emptyset$ is a relation to $A$.

1. Can somone please explain how an empty set can be a subset of a Cartesian Product?
2. In my example, if $R$ is indeed a relation on $A$,  how would you even draw a diagram of this relation?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  Certainly there is a trivial relation on any set in which no element is related to any other element.  Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: The empty set is a subset of any set, even if it's a Cartesian product

Comment: @lulu, I am asking is R a relation to A because empty set is subset of any set, which makes it true?  And my second confused how someone can do a diagram of  $\emptyset \ subseteq$ A $\times$ A. Is it  ordered pair diagram of the Cartesian product?

Comment: I don't understand what it is you are after exactly.  If you are talking about a diagram of a relation where you draw a vertex for each element in the set the relation is over and arrows from one vertex to another iff the first element is related to the second element... then the diagram of the empty relation is very simply the diagram with only vertices and no arrows.

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking.  To define a relation on a set it suffices to specify which elements are related to which other elements.  Declaring that no element is related to any other element certainly does that.  As to a diagram, perhaps it would help if you gave an example of the sort of diagram you have in mind.  For instance, consider the relation in which every element is equivalent to itself and itself only. What does your diagram look like then?

Comment: It's the empty relation.  A relation that contains no pairs and in which *nothing* is related to anything.  That's an acceptable concept.  Why should be be able to "draw" a relation....  Here's a thought problem.  Lets say $A= \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and lets so $a R b\iff a > 1000^b$ or $R= \{(a,b)| a > 1000^b\}$. Draw that relation.

Comment: You've been given a lot of answers here, but I'd provide one more perspective: to see why $\emptyset \subseteq A \times A$, you can first assume the contrary, i.e  $\emptyset \not \subseteq A \times A$. Then by definition of the subsets, we must have some $x \in \emptyset$ such that $x \not \in A \times A$. But empty set cannot contain any objects by definition, hence a contradiction. So given the definitions, you are forced to conclude that $\emptyset \subseteq A \times A$

Comment: And for the second question: To determine whether some set is a relation, you must strictly rely on the given definitions; the ability "to draw a diagram" is not a condition that some set must satisfy in order to be qualified as a relation.

Answer (score 2):

> I am stuck on saying empty set is subset of all sets but in cartesian product it isn't

Sure it is.  Consider $R = \{(a,b)\in A\times A| a\in \emptyset, b\in \emptyset\} \subset A\times A$.

So there aren't any $(a,b)$ where $a \in \emptyset$ and $b\in \emptyset$ then $R = \emptyset\subset A\times A$.

No problem there.

> And how would you even draw a diagram of this if it is relation.

Like this:

$R = $

> 

Or  if a "drawing" is $R = \{$ a list of all the related elements and what they are related to $\}$ then:

$R = \{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \}$.